# Waypoint is not a function error in Angularjs 5

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, frontend

Waypoint has been installed through `npm install waypoint` and I have added this in `angular-cli.json`:

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"],
```

In my `compontent.ts` I have added this:

```js
$('.js--section-features').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction == "down") {
    $('nav').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
  }
}, {
  offset: '60px;'
});
```

After this process I am getting two errors as mentioned:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined.

> zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function

I new to Angular. What is the right way to use waypoint for section navigation?

Comment: Any solution available?

Comment: Found Solution:  Added "scripts": " ["./assets/vendor/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"], " in angular-cli.json and in type script file added " declare var waypoints:any; " in import section.